# @throw & [NSException raise] not working in Objective-C Project OSX

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsexception

I have a project where throwing an exception is not doing anything.
I have this lines of code at the end of *applicationDidFinishLaunching*:

```
@throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"exception name" reason:@"reason" userInfo:nil];

[NSException raise:@"raise exception test" format:@""];
```

I go line by line while debugging and they seem to be doing nothing, the app continues to run and there is no output in the console.

I have checked that "Enable Objective-C Exceptions" is turned on for debug and release modes.
The main class is NSApplication, so there is no chance of messing up "reportException"

Can you give me more things that I should double check to make exceptions work again ?

Comment: Did you build a exception handler around it? If so, is it executed?

Comment: An app usually continues to run after an exception. Add an Exception Breakpoint.